HPCC Systems ECL: Insufficient access rights error using LinearRegression
I am working on a machine learning project using HPCC Systems and ECL to perform linear regression. My dataset consists of mental health prevalence data. While trying to train my model using LinearRegression.OLS, I am encountering the following error:
Error: Insufficient access rights to use embedded code 
(125, 34 - C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\HPCCSystems\bundles_versions\PBblas\V3_0_2\PBblas\internal\Converted.ecl)

This means that the code that is included within an ECL script but requires special permissions or access levels to run.
The error points to a specific file in HPCC Systems installation, which in this case is a part of the PBblas library (Converted.ecl).
my code:
IMPORT ML_Core;
IMPORT LinearRegression;
IMPORT $;

// Record structure for the input dataset
MentalHealthRecord := RECORD
    STRING Entity;
    STRING Code;
    INTEGER Year;
    REAL8 Schizophrenia;
    REAL8 Depression;
    REAL8 Anxiety;
    REAL8 Bipolar;
    REAL8 EatingDisorders;
END;

// Input of dataset as per the record
MentalHealthDs := DATASET('~asn::testing::1-mental-illnesses-prevalence.csv',
                 MentalHealthRecord,
                 CSV(HEADING(1),
                     SEPARATOR(','),
                     TERMINATOR(['\n', '\r\n', '\n\r'])));
                     
OUTPUT(MentalHealthDs, NAMED('InputDataset')); 

// Number of records in the dataset. Split ratio of train:test as a decimal.
recordCount := COUNT(MentalHealthDs);
splitRatio := 0.8; // 80% for training, 20% for testing

// Record structure inheriting dataset record containing the randomizing number
Shuffler := RECORD
    MentalHealthRecord;
    UNSIGNED4 rnd; // A random number
END;

// Add an attribute to the data containing a random number
newDs := PROJECT(MentalHealthDs, TRANSFORM(Shuffler, SELF.rnd := RANDOM(), SELF := LEFT));

// Shuffle by sorting the dataset as per the random number
shuffledDs := SORT(newDs, rnd);

// Split the train and test dataset while taking only the input record attributes
TrainDs := PROJECT(shuffledDs[1..(recordCount * splitRatio)], RECORDOF(MentalHealthDs));
TestDs := PROJECT(shuffledDs[(recordCount * splitRatio + 1)..recordCount], RECORDOF(MentalHealthDs));

OUTPUT(TrainDs, NAMED('TrainDataset'));
OUTPUT(TestDs, NAMED('TestDataset'));

// Append sequential ID to both train and test datasets
ML_Core.AppendSeqID(TrainDs, id, newTrain);
ML_Core.AppendSeqID(TestDs, id, newTest);

OUTPUT(newTrain, NAMED('TrainDatasetID'));
OUTPUT(newTest, NAMED('TestDatasetID'));

// Convert the dataset to Numeric Field for the training
ML_Core.ToField(newTrain, TrainNF);
ML_Core.ToField(newTest, TestNF);

OUTPUT(TrainNF, NAMED('TrainNumericField'));
OUTPUT(TestNF, NAMED('TestNumericField'));

// Split the converted Numeric Field datasets as per the number of independent columns to get X and Y for training 
independent_cols := 4; // Schizophrenia, Anxiety, Bipolar, EatingDisorders

X_train := TrainNF(number < independent_cols + 1);
y_train := PROJECT(TrainNF(number = independent_cols + 1), TRANSFORM(RECORDOF(LEFT), SELF.number := 1, SELF := LEFT));

X_test := TestNF(number < independent_cols + 1);
y_test := PROJECT(TestNF(number = independent_cols + 1), TRANSFORM(RECORDOF(LEFT), SELF.number := 1, SELF := LEFT));

OUTPUT(y_test, NAMED('ActualY'));

// Build the regressor by fitting to the model and predict using test dataset
regressor := LinearRegression.OLS(X_train, y_train).GetModel;
predicted := LinearRegression.OLS().Predict(X_test, regressor);

OUTPUT(predicted, NAMED('PredictedY'));


I have checked my access rights, but the issue persists.
Why am I  getting the "Insufficient access rights" error and how to resolve it?
How can I correctly use LinearRegression.OLS for training the model?
Are there alternative methods or configurations in HPCC Systems ECL for performing linear regression without encountering access rights issues?
